# Migrate core data to add new attribute

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration

I have added new attribute and I need to migrate core data. As a result, I do like this.

Bus.xcDataModel >> Add model version

Then, I add new attribute.  I change persistent store coordinator option as well like this.

```
@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES}
```

But when I add that new attribute, it show me like this. How shall I do?

-[BusService setBus_wap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1742a7320

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator_busservice
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator_busservice != nil)
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator_busservice;

    NSURL *applicationDocumentsDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    NSURL *storeURL = [applicationDocumentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Busservice_new.sqlite"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]] &&
    !self.preloadEnabled)
    {
        NSURL *preloadURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Busservice_new" ofType:@"sqlite"]];

        NSError* err = nil;

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:preloadURL toURL:storeURL error:&err])
        DLog(@"Oops, could not copy preloaded data");
}

    NSError *error = nil;
_persistentStoreCoordinator_busservice = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator_busservice addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES} error:&error])
{
    DLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return _persistentStoreCoordinator_busservice;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From that error it looks like you added a new attribute to your `BusService` entity in Core Data, but did not add the attribute to your `BusService` class. If you want to use accessor methods for this new attribute, you need to update the class as well. Or you can leave the class alone but use `setValue:forKey:` to assign values to the new attribute.